# Jersey XML into Map

Tags: java, xml, jersey

Due to old project decisions, I work on a project that uses Jersey to connect to services that return XML data. Sometimes I could create the bean/pojo/whatever annotated with `XmlRootElement` and use `webTarget.get(MyPojo.class)`

However, if I try to do what I would do with, say, Jackson, and do `webTarget.get(Map.class)` I get the following error:

```
MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/xml, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=interface java.util.Map.
```

My case is, I have a XML that can have arbitrary fields whithin, so the ideal way for me to read it is to read a Map. Is there any way I can do that without having to rely in other libraries? I don't need to serialize data, only deserialize responses from the web services I connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, and it's kinda depressing.

According to the [Unofficial JAXB Guide](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_your_favorite_class.html), you can't use a `Map` as a root element, unless you do a very ugly hack, described there. So, the solutions are:

1. Read as a `String`, and use Jackson to read a `Map` from the string.
2. Do the ugly hack.
3. Describe part of the schema in a bean, but the part that can have variable fields can be deserialized to a `Map`.